# Can i make a clean exe without dll files ? in C#

Tags: c#

- hi , i have a question
- Can i import this dll files in the program itself in C# ?
- Note : the program will not open without them !

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Net 6 supports this, it's called a SingleFileApplication. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Comment: Technically this is a low-quality post (URL post only). It would be better to add a summary and some examples because the URL might change in the future (MS does this all the time).

Answer (score 1):

What you’re referring to is called static linking. As others have mentioned .NET 6 has a concept of a “single file application” that can handle this for you. If you’re using .NET Framework then things get a little more challenging as there’s no out of the box mechanism to do this. Fortunately there are techniques that can make this work — from bundling the library DLLs as resources and extracting them on the fly or using a tool like ilmerge. This is covered in depth here: [Static Linking of libraries created on C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868449/static-linking-of-libraries-created-on-c-sharp-net)